# Google Sitemap: Errors

Tags: google-search-console, xml-sitemap

I have just submitted my sitemap to google and it is giving below kind of error.

[image]

Errors are

**Rating is missing required best and/or worst values**

**Value in property "reviewCount" must be positive**

Am I missing something in `sitemap.xml` file?

How to fix above errors?

If I didn't fix above error it will affect my website ranking or not?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about SEO.